# PHP: Image does not get saved at specified path

Tags: php

I use the following php script for processing a picture upload:

```
// receive image data
$imgUrl = $_POST['imgUrl'];
$imgInitW = $_POST['imgInitW'];
$imgInitH = $_POST['imgInitH'];
$imgW = $_POST['imgW'];
$imgH = $_POST['imgH'];
$imgY1 = $_POST['imgY1'];
$imgX1 = $_POST['imgX1'];
$cropW = $_POST['cropW'];
$cropH = $_POST['cropH'];

// set image quality
$jpeg_quality = 100;

// define output name
$output_filename = "uploads/users/croppedImg_".rand();

// make sure only specific types of images get uploaded
$what = getimagesize($imgUrl);
// get extension of image url
$imgUrlParts = explode(".", $imgUrl);
$imgExtension = end($imgUrlParts);
switch(strtolower($imgExtension)) {
    case 'png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $type = '.png';
        break;
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'jpg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $type = '.jpeg';
        break;
    case 'gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $type = '.gif';
        break;
    default: die('image type not supported');
}

$resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgW, $imgH, $imgInitW, $imgInitH);   

$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);
imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $resizedImage, 0, 0, $imgX1, $imgY1, $cropW, $cropH, $cropW, $cropH);   

imagejpeg($dest_image, $output_filename.$type, $jpeg_quality);

$response = array(
    "status" => 'success',
    "url" => $output_filename.$type 
);

print json_encode($response);
```

My problem is that the picture never arrives at the directory specified in $output_filename. Does anyone have a clue why? Maybe someone knows some additional code that needs to be used here.

Comment: Does the folder exist?  Does the webserver (apache?) have write permission?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have error reporting turned on to see if there's some errors thrown around:

```
// Add these to the top of your php script if you can't turn it on in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Then I would check that the image is being created properly. To do that you could replace the filename argument in `imagejpeg` with `NULL` to have the image output directly to the browser. If it's working, then it's probably a problem with permissions. Give the output location as an absolute path, and for debugging use a fixed filename.

If it still doesn't work, please post any errors that show up.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating code.from scratch please use the available plugin

One such plugin which is easy to use is easyphpthumbnail below is a link
http://www.mywebmymail.com/?q=content/easyphpthumbnail-class